# MySQL WHERE clause is getting ignored in SELECT MIN() subquery

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

I'm running this query:

```
SELECT prop_numero, prop_id, prop_fase_id
FROM propiedades 
WHERE prop_numero = (
    SELECT MIN(prop_numero)
    FROM propiedades 
    WHERE prop_numero > 11 AND prop_fase_id = 2
);
```

And get this:

```
| prop_numero | prop_id | prop_fase_id |
|-------------|---------|--------------|
| 111         |     166 |            1 |
|-------------|---------|--------------|
| 111         |     233 |            6 |
|-------------|---------|--------------|
| 111         |     657 |            2 |
|-------------|---------|--------------|
| 111         |     658 |            4 |
|-------------|---------|--------------|
```

I'm expecting just this:

```
| prop_numero | prop_id | prop_fase_id |
|-------------|---------|--------------|
| 111         |     657 |            2 |
|-------------|---------|--------------|
```

Not always, but some times the second WHERE clause (prop_fase_id = 2) gets ignored. It is normal that the first WHERE clause of the subquery finds more than 1 row, so there's where the second clause should filter out most leaving just one, but no, it gets ignored.

Why? I have tried to structure with different subqueries but I don't the result I need.

Comment: What do you mean by ignored? Explain what is it you are trying to achieve and if possible the table descriptions and some sample data.

Comment: Thanks Juan. I mean it doesn't filter out the rows that does not have '2' in column prop_fase_id. I'll post some data.

Comment: I think you need to explain more about what you want as outcome. It is not clear why you are using min() for example. The subquery will resolve to an prop_numero, in this case 111. But the main query will show all recods where prop_numero is 111 in this example, all the records. If you want jus one result the condition of the main query should be on the id instead of the prop_numero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the column prop_numero is notr a key column, you also need to add prop_fase_id = 2 to the WHERE, i.e.

```
SELECT prop_numero, prop_id, prop_fase_id
FROM propiedades 
WHERE prop_numero = (
    SELECT MIN(prop_numero)
    FROM propiedades 
    WHERE prop_numero > 11 AND prop_fase_id = 2
) AND prop_fase_id = 2;
```

Comment: This is it. Thanks!